# How to Recover a Remote Desktop VM

Tags: centos

I need to recover a remote desktop VM with minimum install that I deleted.

The VM is a remote VM that connects to a physical server from connecting to a remote desktop or ssh putty.

How do I recover the VM. It has all my files. I am a beginner. I may not know that much. Please help me out.

I am using CentOS 8 as well as this picture shows my release, version type and kernel version.

release

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="8 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="8"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 8 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:8"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-8"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="8"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8"
```

version

```
centos-release-8.1-1.1911.0.8.el8.x86_64
```

kernel

```
4.18.0-147.5.1.el8_1.x86_64
```

[image: picture1]
[image: picture2]
[image: picture3]

Comment: please include the actual text, not a picture of text

Comment: you need to connect to physical host hosting the VM to salvage VM's disk. Is this vmware ? xen ? or are you using either azure, AWS or GCP ?

Comment: I am not sure which one I have. Maybe I can find out through putty. However, I do not know the command.

Comment: Unless you know what the host supervisor is, you will need to find someone who knows. It may be they have a backup

Comment: I believe it is vmware.